# Select same records that only have different values for a particular column

Tags: sql, oracle, select, distinct

Below is an example of my customer table. There some records having multiple values in BIRTHDAY DATE (by mistake or so). I only want to select those records that have same values for LASTNAME, MIDDLENAME, FIRSTNAME, SSN but different BIRTHDAY:

**Member table**

```
LASTNAME   MIDDLENAME   FIRSTNAME    SSN      BIRTHDAY
Jones      M            Carol        1234     17-DEC-45
Jones      M            Carol        1234     17-DEC-45
Jones      M            Carol        4425     20-APR-70
Black      S            Ted          5555     15-MAY-57
Roberts    T            Cole         1412     14-MAY-57
Roberts    T            Cole         1412     20-OCT-57
Roberts    S            Cole         1412     15-MAY-57
```

I would like the result to be:

```
LASTNAME   MIDDLEANME  FIRSTNAME    SSN      BIRTHDAY
Roberts    T           Cole         1412     14-MAY-57
Roberts    T           Cole         1412     20-OCT-57
```

Notice that there were few accounts with same SSN or full name in the table, they are not selected since they don't have everything same. Also Jones M. Carol with 1234 as SSN is not selected either since she does not have different Birthday for two different account.

This is my SQL query that I have so far and this is not working well necessarily as it shows the results without duplication which I don't want to see.

```
SELECT x.FIRST_NM, x.MDL_NM, x.LAST_NM, x.SSN, x.BRTH_DT
FROM Member_table x
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT FIRST_NM, MDL_NM, LAST_NM, SSN, COUNT(*)
    from Member_table
    WHERE CURRENT_RECORD_IN = 'Y'
    group by FIRST_NM, MDL_NM, LAST_NM, SSN
    having count(distinct BRTH_DT) > 1
)
ORDER BY FIRST_NM ASC, LAST_NM ASC, MDL_NM ASC, SSN ASC;
```

Any advice for this query?

Comment: You need a condition x.FIRST_NM = sub.FIRST_NM AND x.MDL_NM = sub.MDL_NM ... etc... in your EXISTS clause.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a single table scan using the `COUNT(...) OVER (...)` analytic function:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/743779/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE member_table ( LASTNAME, MIDDLENAME, FIRSTNAME, SSN, BIRTHDAY ) AS
SELECT 'Jones',   'M',         'Carol',      1234, DATE '1945-12-17' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jones',   'M',         'Carol',      1234, DATE '1945-12-17' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jones',   'M',         'Carol',      4425, DATE '1970-04-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Black',   'S',         'Ted',        5555, DATE '1957-05-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Roberts', 'T',         'Cole',       1412, DATE '1957-05-14' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Roberts', 'T',         'Cole',       1412, DATE '1957-10-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Roberts', 'S',         'Cole',       1412, DATE '1957-05-15' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT m.*,
         COUNT( DISTINCT BIRTHDAY ) OVER (
           PARTITION BY LASTNAME, MIDDLENAME, FIRSTNAME, SSN
         ) AS ct
  FROM   Member_table m
)
WHERE   ct > 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/743779/1/0)**:

```
| LASTNAME | MIDDLENAME | FIRSTNAME |  SSN |             BIRTHDAY | CT |
|----------|------------|-----------|------|----------------------|----|
|  Roberts |          T |      Cole | 1412 | 1957-05-14T00:00:00Z |  2 |
|  Roberts |          T |      Cole | 1412 | 1957-10-20T00:00:00Z |  2 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your conditions in the EXISTS clause.

```
SELECT x.FIRST_NM, x.MDL_NM, x.LAST_NM, x.SSN, x.BRTH_DT
FROM Member_table x
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT MT.FIRST_NM, MT.MDL_NM, MT.LAST_NM, MT.SSN, COUNT(*)
    from Member_table MT
    WHERE MT.CURRENT_RECORD_IN = 'Y'
      AND x.FIRST_NM = MT.FIRST_NM
      AND x.MDL_NM = MT.MDL_NM
      AND x.LAST_NM = MT.LAST_NM 
      AND x.SSN = MT.SSN
    group by MT.FIRST_NM, MT.MDL_NM, MT.LAST_NM, MT.SSN
    having count(distinct MT.BRTH_DT) > 1
)
ORDER BY FIRST_NM ASC, LAST_NM ASC, MDL_NM ASC, SSN ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT x.*
FROM Member_table x
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM Member_table x1 
              WHERE x1.FIRST_NM = x.FIRST_NM AND x1.MDL_NM = x.MDL_NM AND
                    x1.LAST_NM = x.LAST_NM AND x1.SSN = x.SSN AND 
                    x1.BIRTHDAY <> x.BIRTHDAY
             );
```

For your current query you were not established any relation (i.e. *referenced*) between two queries which is actually required.